# Different behaviour of ImageButtons and their images , between Lollipop and preLollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, imagebutton

I have a Toolbar , which I use as a bottom Navigation bar. My problem is being illustrated in the picture below.

[image]

The Emulator on the right is a Google Nexus 4 - API 21 and the Emulator on the left is Samsung Note 2 - API 18. Also I have the same problem with all the mobiles that run Android OS < Lollipop.

Here is the code from the Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="35dp"
android:background="#ffffff">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/categories"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/treding"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <!--
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/treding"
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:src="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:background="@drawable/settings1"/>
        -->
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is the code where I set the Image Buttons:

```
/**
 * Button toolbar changing activated Button
 */
public void setColorNavigationButton(String button){

    if (button.equals("Latest")) {
        home.setImageResource(R.drawable.home_red);
        categories.setImageResource(R.drawable.categories);
        treding.setImageResource(R.drawable.treding);
    } else if(button.equals("Collections")){
        home.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        categories.setImageResource(R.drawable.categories_red);
        treding.setImageResource(R.drawable.treding);
    } else if(button.equals("Trending")){
        home.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        categories.setImageResource(R.drawable.categories);
        treding.setImageResource(R.drawable.treding_red);
    } else{
        home.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
        categories.setImageResource(R.drawable.categories);
        treding.setImageResource(R.drawable.treding);
    }
}
```

Also, I have tried all the choices of the `android:scaleType`, but sometimes the images disappeared and I can't reach the desirable result.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: and you are setting the images via src or via background? remember ImageButtons put a default gray background.

Comment: I edit my Question so you can see @Raykud

Comment: I don't think this is an OS issue.  I think this is a scaling issue.  The Note 2 has a pixel density of about 260 dpi while the Nexus 4 has one of about 320 dpi.  The first would pull resources from the hdpi bucket while the second would pull resources from the xhdpi bucket.  If you only have resources in one of those, then the scaling is going to be off.

Comment: Eventually after the help of @Raykud , I changed the background of the `ImageButtons` to `android:background="#fff"` and all fixed!